# Why does Amado repeat the word morte in the title of his novel A Morte e a Morte de Quincas Berro d'Água?

Tags: title, portuguese-language, jorge-amado, the-double-death-of-quincas

The title of Jorge Amado's novel *A Morte e a Morte de Quincas Berro d'Água* (1959) has been translated in various ways:

- [*The Two Deaths of Quincas Wateryell*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Two_Deaths_of_Quincas_Wateryell),
- [*The Double Death of Quincas Water-Bray*](https://www.penguinrandomhouse.com/books/308730/the-double-death-of-quincas-water-bray-by-jorge-amado-translated-by-gregory-rabassa-introduction-by-rivka-galchen/) (Gregory Rabassa's translation),
- [*Die drei Tode des Jochen Wasserbrüller*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jorge_Amado#Werke) (literally "The three deaths of ...", German translation, 1991),
- *Der Tod und der Tod des Quincas Wasserschrei* (German translation by Luis Ruby, 2013),
- [*Les Deux Morts de Quinquin-la-Flotte*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jorge_Amado#Romans) (French translation by Georges Boisvert, 1971),
- [*La muerte y la muerte de Quincas Berro Dágua*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_muerte_y_la_muerte_de_Quincas_Berro_D%C3%A1gua) (Spanish),
- [*La doppia morte di Quincas l'acquaiolo*](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_doppia_morte_di_Quincas_l%27acquaiolo) (Italian).

In the above list of translations, only the second German translation and the Spanish translation repeat the word for "death"; the other translations use a word for "double" or a numeral instead. Brazilian Portuguese obviously has words for "two" and [double](https://dictionary.reverso.net/english-portuguese/double), so it is hard to believe that the repetition of "morte" is accidental, in spite of the translations. Hence my question: is there a specific reason for the repetition of the word "morte" in the Portuguese title? If yes, what is that reason?

Answer (score 1):

When I have read it (very long ago, and in yet another language), I parsed the title as

```
(A Morte) e (a Morte de Quincas Berro d'Água)
```

that is *The Death* in general, and *some particular death*. After all, if I am not mistaken, in the novel Quincas dies thrice, so two, or double, are definitely off.

That said, I don't know if my reading matches the Amado's intentions.

Comment: I don't understand this answer since it raises more questions. (1) What are your arguments for parsing the title like this? (2) How does the novel talk about death in general? (3) What are Quincas's three deaths? (And if he does die three times, how does that fit with your parsing of the title?)

Comment: @Tsundoku: this answer is just saying that the grammar of Portuguese (or whatever language the answerer read the book in) leaves the reading "*Death* (in general) and *Death* (in particular of Quincas)" as a possibility. I don't know Portuguese, but the corresponding title in French, another Romance language, would allow that.

Comment: (1) There is no arguments, it is just natural. (2) The Death is constantly present in the background (don't ask for arguments). (3), the third (or rather the first) death is his break-up with the family.